# Scanf() not waiting for an integer input

Tags: c, scanf

The second time I call scanf in this program, the function doesn't wait for user input. I know with chars you have to leave a space before the format specifier (which I have tried) but can't figure out whats happening with this int. Thanks!

```
// Program to calculate the number of elasped days between two dates.

#include <stdio.h>

struct date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

int valueofN (struct date d);
int f(int year, int month);
int g(int month);

int main (void)
{
    struct date date1, date2;

    printf("Enter the first date - dd:mm:yyyy : ");
    scanf("%i:%i:%i", &date1.day, &date1.month, &date1.year);

    printf("Enter the second date - dd:mm:yyyy : ");
    scanf("%i:%i:%i", &date2.day, &date2.month, &date2.year);

    // The line above here is where the problem lies ^^^^

    long int N1 = valueofN (date1);
    long int N2 = valueofN (date2);

    printf("Number of elasped days = %li\n", (N2 - N1));

    return 0;
}

// Functions

int valueofN (struct date d)
{
    int N;
    return N = (1461 * (f(d.year, d.month) / 4) + 153 * (g(d.month) / 5) +d.day);
}

int f(int year, int month)
{
    if (month <= 2)
        return (year - 1);
    else
        return year;
}

int g(int month)
{
    if (month <= 2)
        return (month + 13);
    else
        return (month + 1);
}
```

Comment: What does your input look like? As you including the colon in your input?

Comment: e.g. for todays date      24:08:2018

Comment: The second time around, its not even waiting for an input though. That's my problem.

Comment: I compiled your code with **gcc** and there is no problem. What **compiler** do you use and what **terminal environment** are you running your program in?

Comment: @user3121023 Ah thanks!  %d did it. I'm not really sure of the difference between %i and %d. I need to do some reading!

Comment: @KaiserKatze Yes it compiles ok, the problem is fixed, just needed to replace %i with %d, thanks.

Comment: @PaulB Sometimes, especially **terminal enviroment** causes similiar problems. that's why I asked. :)

Comment: @KaiserKatze I'm using the CS50 IDE

Comment: @user3121023 Ok thanks.

Comment: How could switching from `%i` to `%d` solve your problem? The program works fine for me as it is (at least the input, I didn't understand or verify the computations).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I'm not too sure but it did fix the problem. With `%d`, the program now waits for the second input. (BTW If anyone is interested, I think the formula for calculating the elasped days is not correct - the code is an exercise from the Stephen Kochan book "Programming in C", and the formula was given.)

Comment: Tip: when `scanf()` does not behave at expected, best that code checks the return value of `scanf()` like `if (scanf("%i:%i:%i", &date1.day, &date1.month, &date1.year) != 3)  printf("oops!\n"):`  This will quickly narrow the problem.

Comment: @chux very good advice, and often forgotten.

Comment: @chux Thanks, I noticed there was a problem and added another printf statement to print out the contents of date2. I saw that they were filled with garbage values. I'll try your method though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is due to format specifier `%i`.

You may not observe any difference in behaviour `%d` and `%i`When used with a `printf()`, but when used with `scanf` the significance is obvious, that `%i` takes an integer value as integer value with decimal, hex or octal type, based on some prefix, such that 
if it begins with `0x` its taken a Hex, when preceded with `0`, its taken as an Octal value. When you use `%d` in a `scanf`, it assume the base 10.

So, you need to replace `%i` with `%d`.

Additionally, make a habit of standard library reading man pages of the functions that you are planning to use.
For example, [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf), section **"Conversions"** states that,

> i
>
> Matches an optionally signed integer; the next pointer must be a pointer to int. The integer is read in base 16 if it begins with 0x or 0X, in base 8 if it begins with 0, and in base 10 otherwise. Only characters that correspond to the base are used.

Also in section **"Return Value"**, it states,

> Return Value
>   These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.

Getting the return values from `scanf`, and addition some error handling for unexpected return will save you a lot of pain going ahead.

**Additional Inputs:**

1. Its usually preferred/recommended to name your function with verb (or an action) rather than anything that makes no sense.

For example,

```
int valueofN (struct date d);
int f(int year, int month);
int g(int month);
```

If I am reviewing your code, I don't know what this function does. Going ahead, name functions and other variables in such a way that it makes sense.

2. Use compatible data types

For example,

```
long int N1 = valueofN (date1);
long int N2 = valueofN (date2);
```

`N1` and `N2` are of the data type `long int` while `valueofN()` is returning an `int`. Its a different data type, there is no immediate harm with this code, but there is a potential harm in this practice going ahead.

3. Some improvement

This

```
int valueofN (struct date d)
{
    int N;
    return N = (1461 * (f(d.year, d.month) / 4) + 153 * (g(d.month) / 5)+ d.day);
}
```

could have been

```
int valueofN (struct date d)
{
    return (int)(1461 * (f(d.year, d.month) / 4) + 153 * (g(d.month) / 5) +d.day);
}
```

4. Some more improvement: You should always validate the data entered by user (unless you don't know the lower and higher bound values). For example, user can enter `50` for `month`. It isn't validated. Handle that at the input stage itself. Make that a habit.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the advice! I've only been programming for 4 weeks so I've a long way to go and i'll take all your advice on board. Yes I usually do validate user input with a printf error message and a do-while loop. Thanks again ;)

Comment: The function names and formula were given in the text book example I was working on. I usually do name them appropriately. The functions were part of the formula for N. I too thought that they make no sense! :)